# Как сделать ввод пароля(из цифр) в телеграм боте для авторизации

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Как сделать ввод пароля из цифр. Есть такой код, для кнопки, но его придеться отлавливать через колбеки, пушить по числу после нажатия кнопки и если нажал ок, то закончить ввод пароля, есть ли решения попроще?

p.s код изначально нашел на php в теме: [How to get data from inline keyboard as single result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601179/how-to-get-data-from-inline-keyboard-as-single-result).

```
var inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
               {
                    new []
                    {
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1","1"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2","2"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("3","3"),
                        
                    },
                    new []
                    {
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("4","4"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("5","5"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("6","6"),
                    },
                    new []
                    {
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("7","7"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("8","8"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("9","9"),
                    }
                    ,
                    new []
                    {
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("<","<"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Ok","Ok"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("0","0"),
                    }
                });
```

Comment: ссылку на другой вопрос SO давать можно

Comment: добавил ссылку на вопрос